# TCP Client: receive bytes from TCP Connection - Java, Android

Tags: java, android, tcp, client, bufferedinputstream

I am developing an Android App which receives some data from a server.
I used this tutorial for the TCP Client: [TCP Tutorial](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/#.V_EiEpOLQnO)

Unlike in the tutorial, I need the data as **byte[]** and not as a String but I can't figure out how to do this.

My TCP Client:

```
public class TCPClient {

private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private BufferedInputStream input;
private byte[] serverMessage; // message received from server

private boolean mRun = false;

/**
 *  Constructor:
 *  OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server.
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Connection thread
 */
public void run() {
    mRun = true;

    try {
        // Server address:
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(10.0.0.170);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        // Connection socket:
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4848);

        try {
            // Input stream from server:
            input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // Listen for messages from server:
            while (mRun) {
                int bytesRead = input.read();
                serverMessage = new byte[bytesRead];

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }

                serverMessage = null; // reset serverMessage
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

/**
 * The method messageReceived(byte[] message) must be implemented in the
 * MainActivity class at on asynckTask doInBackground
 */
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(byte[] message);
}

}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// TCP Connection:
private TCPClient mTcpClient;
connectTask mConnectTask;

Button connectBtn;

// Debugging variable:
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Relate Button and EditText from java to the one in XML:
    connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);

    mConnectTask = new connectTask(); // prepare for TCP connection

    // Connect to Server after connect btn pressed
    connectBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connect button pressed.");
                    mConnectTask.execute(); // starts Async task
                }
            }
    );
}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], byte[], TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(byte[]... message) {

        // Create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {

            @Override
            // Implementation of messageReceived method
            public void messageReceived(byte[] message) {
                publishProgress(message); // calls the onProgressUpdate method
            }

        });

        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        byte b[] = values[0];

        // TODO delete
        String str = new String(b, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Data received: " + str);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int c = b[i] & 0xFF;
            Log.d(TAG, "c: " + c);

            // Further processing where data is needed as byte[]

        }
    }
}
}
```

The Log.d

```
Log.d(TAG, "Data received: " + str);
```

logs out that data (unrecognizable bytes) is received. But when I log out c, which is supposed to be the received byte as an int, it is always 0.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: `serverMessage = new byte[bytesRead];`. So you create a byte buffer. This buffer is emty or randomly filled . You are reading nothing into that buffer. And then you throw it away. `.read()` will only read one byte. So your messages can not be longer than 255 bytes.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps. I have found no proper way to replace the readline() method for a byte[]. Can you tell me a method or way I could use instead?

Comment: You should declare a byte buffer like `byte buffer[2048];` And then read in that buffer like `int nread = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`.

Comment: Thank you once again @greenapps. But then I have an int and I'm looking for a byte[] in my serverMessage variable. How can I achieve this? Sorry if it's a stupid question but I'm new to this.

Comment: That whole byte buffer is of course filled with ... bytes now. That integer nread` only tells you how many bytes are read. How many bytes are now in `buffer`.